# N-Queens Puzzle

Tags: recursion, f#, depth-first-search, backtracking, n-queens

The N-Queens puzzle can be solved in many ways. One is by a depth-first-search backtracking algorithm.

Below is my generalized version using mutual recursion:

```
let dfsBacktrack initialValue solved getNextItems = 

    let rec procCurrent path =
        match solved path with
        | true -> Some path
        | false -> procNext path (getNextItems path) 

    and procNext path nextItems =
        match nextItems with
        | [] -> None
        | next::tail ->
            match procCurrent (next::path) with
            | Some solution -> Some solution
            | None -> procNext path tail

    procCurrent [ initialValue ]
```

The main problem with it is that it is not tail recursive so it builds up the stack with the limitations that leads to.

Anyway solving the N-Queens problem with it could look like:

```
let queensProblem n = 
    if n < 4 then failwith "n must be greater than or equal to 4"

    let solved queens = queens |> List.length = n

    let getFields row = [0..n-1] |> List.map (fun col -> col, row)

    let isValidField (col, row) (qcol, qrow) = 
        col <> qcol && row <> qrow // horz and vert
        && abs (col - qcol) <> abs (row - qrow) // diagonals

    let reduceByQueen fields queen =
        fields
        |> List.where (fun pos -> isValidField pos queen)

    let getValidFields queens = 
        let row = queens |> List.head |> (snd)
        queens
        |> List.fold reduceByQueen (getFields (row + 1))

    dfsBacktrack (0, 0) solved getValidFields |> Option.get |> List.rev
```

For `n < 27` it finds a solution fairly quickly.

For `n = 8` it produces the output: `[(0, 0); (4, 1); (7, 2); (5, 3); (2, 4); (6, 5); (1, 6); (3, 7)]`

The above algorithm can also be used to find a solution for the Knight's Tour-problem:

```
let knightsTour n = 
    if n < 5 then failwith "n must be greater than or equal to 5"

    let solved positions = positions |> List.length = n*n
    let onboard (x, y) = x >= 0 && x < n && y >= 0 && y < n
    let offsets = [ (2, 1); (2, -1); (1, 2); (1, -2); (-1, 2); (-1, -2); (-2, 1); (-2, -1) ]
    let offset (x, y) (dx, dy) = x + dx, y + dy

    let nextPositions path = 
        let pos = path |> List.head
        let rec collect pos path recall = 
            let posses = 
                offsets 
                |> List.map (fun o -> offset pos o)
                |> List.where (fun p -> onboard p && not (path |> List.contains p))

            // Warnsdorff's rule
            match recall with
            | true -> 
                posses
                |> List.map (fun pt -> pt, collect pt (pt::path) false |> List.length)
                |> List.sortBy (fun (_, count) -> count)
                |> List.map (fun (pt, _) -> pt)
            | false -> posses

        collect pos path true

    dfsBacktrack (0, 0) solved nextPositions
```

---

Another algorithm for the N-Queens problem is the [Min-conflicts algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-conflicts_algorithm), which shows to be much more efficient:

```
let queensProblemByMinConflicts maxIterations n =
    if n < 4 then failwith "n must be greater than or equal to 4"

    let rand = Random(5)

    let initQueens = 
        Array.init n id 
        |> Array.map (fun i -> i, (i * 2) % n) // map (fun i -> i, rand.Next() % n)  //

    let hasConflict (q1c, q1r) (q2c, q2r) = q1c = q2c || q1r = q2r || abs (q1c - q2c) = abs (q1r - q2r)

    let getConflicts queen queens = 
        let conflicts = 
            queens 
            |> Array.where (fun q -> q <> queen && hasConflict queen q)

        match conflicts with
        | [||] -> None
        | arr -> Some (arr)

    let countConflicts queen queens = 
        match getConflicts queen queens with
        | None -> 0
        | Some conflicts -> conflicts |> Array.length

    let indicesWithConflicts queens = 
        queens 
        |> Array.mapi (fun i q -> (i, q))
        |> Array.where (fun (_, q) -> countConflicts q queens > 0)
        |> Array.map (fst)

    let minimizeConflicts (qc, qr) queens = 
        [| 0..n-1 |]
        |> Array.where (fun r -> r <> qr)
        |> Array.map (fun r -> (qc, r))
        |> Array.groupBy (fun q -> countConflicts q queens)
        |> Array.sortBy (fun (k, _) -> k)
        |> Array.head 
        |> fun (_, qs) -> qs.[rand.Next(0, qs |> Array.length)]

    let rec nextState queens iteration =
        match indicesWithConflicts queens with
        | [||] -> Some queens
        | conflicts -> 
            match iteration with
            | _ when iteration = maxIterations -> None
            | _ -> 
                let curQueenIndex = conflicts.[rand.Next(0, conflicts |> Array.length)]
                let curQueen = minimizeConflicts queens.[curQueenIndex] queens
                queens.[curQueenIndex] <- curQueen
                nextState queens (iteration + 1)

    nextState initQueens 0
```

From an initial full - most likely invalid - configuration of N queens on the board (one queen per column), it recursively chooses randomly a queen with conflicts and positions that in its column on a field with the smallest number of conflicts. If more fields have the same smallest number of conflicts one is randomly chosen among them. In the above algorithm `maxIterations` makes it possible to return with no valid solution found instead of just continue infinitely. `nextState` is tail recursive.

With `let rand = Random(5)` and `n = 8` the following result is produced:

```
[|(0, 4); (1, 1); (2, 3); (3, 5); (4, 7); (5, 2); (6, 0); (7, 6)|]
```

---

I'm interested in any comment, but improvements of and tips about the use of F# as a language are very welcome.